# How find structure index in a structure-TArray?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

There is a function on BP that looks for an empty slot in the array and fills it. When trying to rewrite it in c++, it throws the error C2678 "binary"==": an operator accepting a left operand of the type "const FSlotStructure" was not found (or there is no acceptable conversion)"[image]
The variables in the picture correspond to the variables in the code. The Find() function itself does not search for the FSlotStructure variable in the Array Inventory array. What is the mistake?

The function below is custom, because "FIND" and "SetArrayElem" functions from UKismetArrayLibrary and could not be used directly.

```
void UInventoryComponent::CreateStack(FSlotStructure& ContentToAdd)
{
    //TArray<FSlotStructure> Inventory;

    int32 Index;

    for (auto& SlotStructure : Inventory)
    {
        int32 NewIndex = Inventory.Find(SlotStructure, Index);

        Inventory.Insert(ContentToAdd, NewIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop looks odd. For every item in `Inventory` you add an item to `Inventory`? Is that on purpose?

Comment: The error seems quite clear. You're doing a `find`, and to find something, you need to be able to match it. But is there's no equals comparison operator defined for the type, you can't see if it's a match, right?

Comment: Exactly, because everything works in BP, but Inventory.Find(Slot Structure, Index) itself also gives an error C2678.
True, but what exactly? I need to find the index of an element in an array and put it in a variable.
It is logical that the loop does this. But what and with what should be compared in the end?

Comment: Is `FSlotStructure` a built-in, is it generated by BP or is it your own creation?

Comment: Own in BP and in c++

Comment: I think in C++ you need just insert the element to the array if not found. No loop as shown by you do not required.  Also give `operator==` for your `FSlotStructure`.

Comment: Did you define `bool FSlotStructure::operator==(const FSlotStructure&) const;` ?

Comment: Ted Lyngmo, сould you write what is meant in the final code?

Comment: @neoluna Not really because I don't know what the definition of `FSlotStructure` looks like. Implementing  `operator==` for the class should be straight forward though. Just `return member_variable1 == rhs.member_variable1 && member_variable2 == rhs.member_variable2 ...;` - As long as all the member variables has an `operator==`, that should work.

Comment: USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FSlotStructure
{
 GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

 //AItem* Item;

 UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Inventory")
 FItemStructure ItemStructure;

 UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Inventory")
 int32 Quantity;
};

Comment: I have no idea what those macros do. You could try adding the function I suggested to the class definition, `bool operator==(const FSlotStructure& rhs) const { return static_cast<const BlueprintType&>(*this) == static_cast<const BlueprintType&>(rhs) && ItemStructure == rhs.ItemStructure && Quantity == rhs.Quantity; }` - but I'd be surprised if it's that's easy.

Comment: It didn't work, but thanks for helping you Ted Lyngmo and everyone else!

Comment: You're welcome. Just a note: The above assumes that `USTRUCT(BlueprintType)` means that `FSlotStructure` inherits from `BlueprintType` - if it doesn't, remove the first part, this: `static_cast<const BlueprintType&>(*this) == static_cast<const BlueprintType&>(rhs) &&`

Answer (score 0):

Everything has been resolved, at least the code compiles without errors. All I had to do was add it to FSlotStructure

```
operator bool() const
{

return true;

}
```